# How to say "at the expensive/cost of"?

Tags: translation

I want to say the following:

> 过了这几十年，中国的经济发展了很多，但是 ［at the expense of]中国的环境。

I'm not sure if the last part of the sentence is how I would say "at the expense of China's environment"; it was more of a literal translation.

Could someone please help me correctly translate this?

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with trying to translate English idioms or sentence structures word for word into Chinese. I would suggest that something like this would capture your intended meaning in a more natural way:

`这几十年来，中国的经济发展了很多，但却牺牲了自然环境。`

This suggests that the environment was *collateral damage*. If you wanted to put more emphasis on the extent of environmental destruction as the *source* of growth:

`这几十年来，中国牺牲了生态环境，换取经济的快速发展。`

Comment: I don't know if I would call it an idiom. "At the expense of" has a very literal meaning.

Comment: @tofu_bacon That's why I also said "sentence structure" ;)  I'm not sure which it is, but I just meant in general. Many English phrases don't have a nice fully compatible equivalent in Chinese.

Answer (score 3):

What we often hear nowadays in the news reports or critics is that “这是以破坏/牺牲环境为代价的”. Hence you can see 'at the expense / cost of' can be translated into '以...为代价'.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the original with the following sentence:

..., 可是中國的環境卻付出了很高的代價

Comment: Is it meant to be 环 not 还?

Answer (score 2):

這幾十年來, 中國經濟長足增長, 卻為此犧牲了自然生態.

If you want to maintain the order of the clauses, you can add "為此" to emphasize/highlight the relation of the economy and the environment.

Comment: is it awkward to use "为此“ in this way?

Comment: I don't think so ....